# Regex - Match a string up to a digit or a specific string

Tags: regex

I am working in python and there I have a list of countries that I would like to clean. Most countries are already written the way I want them to be. However, some country names have a one- or two-digit number attached or there is a text in brackets appended. Here's a sample of that list:

```
Argentina
Australia1
Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region
Côte d'Ivoire
Curaçao
Guinea-Bissau
Indonesia8
```

The part that I want to capture would look like this:

```
Argentina
Australia
Bolivia
China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region
Côte d'Ivoire
Curaçao
Guinea-Bissau
Indonesia
```

The best solution that I was able to come up with is `^[a-zA-Z\s,ô'ç-]+`. However, this leaves country names that are followed by a text in parentheses with a trailing white space.

This means I would like to match the entire country name unless there is a digit or a white space followed by an open bracket, then I would like it to stop before the digit or the  `(`

I know that I could probably solve this in two steps but I am also reasonably sure that it should be possible to define a pattern that can do it in one step. Since I am anyway in the process of getting familiar with regex, I thought this would be a nice thing to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try `^([^\d \n]| +[^\d (\n])+` or, if you can guarantee your input doesn't contain double-spaces, the slightly simpler `^([^\d \n]| [^\d(\n])+`
(The `^` character inside `[]` excludes the following characters, see https://regexone.com/lesson/excluding_characters)

Technically, the regex I've given omits trailing spaces, but for your application it doesn't sound like that would be a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. In my particular case the `\n` is not necessary because I actually deal with elements in a list that are evaluated individually but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough reputation to comment on the other answer, but I'm not sure `^(.+(?=\d| \()|.+)` works if there are two-digit numbers, like 'Indonesia82'

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it does not. I should have included such an example in my sample list as well. I did not find a quick way to improve Ron's pattern so that it would work with any number size. Hence, I will probably use your pattern. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The pattern can be written as matching any char except digits, parenthesis or whitespace chars. And that part by itself can be optionally repeated preceded by a space.

```
^[^\d\s()]+(?: [^\d\s()]+)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\d\s()]+` Match 1+ times any char except a digit, whitespace char or parenthesis using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[^\d\s()]+` Same match as above
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nKwUl8/1)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you simply convert the strings you don't want to empty strings, using the regular expression

```
\d+$| +\(.*\)
```

with the multiline flag set, causing `^` and `$` to respectively match the beginning and end of a line, rather than the beginning and end of the string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4rj4PE/1)

The expression matches one or more digits at the end of a line or one or more spaces followed by a string that is enclosed in matching parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the regex here https://regex101.com/r/dupn18/1
This should do the trick

```py
In [1]: import re

In [2]: pattern = re.compile(r'(.+(?=\d| \()|.+)')

In [3]: data = """Argentina
   ...: Australia1
   ...: Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
   ...: China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region
   ...: Côte d'Ivoire
   ...: Curaçao
   ...: Guinea-Bissau
   ...: Indonesia8""".splitlines()

In [4]: [pattern.search(country).group() for country in data]
Out[4]:
['Argentina',
 'Australia',
 'Bolivia',
 'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region',
 "Côte d'Ivoire",
 'Curaçao',
 'Guinea-Bissau',
 'Indonesia']
```

Comment: Thanks! That works quite nicely and I think I understood the pattern.